# Arabic in java error

Tags: java

I'm working currently on java project that uses Arabic Language, I found difficulty in writing in Arabic as shown in the image:

[image]

1. I wrote Arabic without any edit.
2. I added a `reverse()` method, it worked good but the letters aren't attached to each other, they're separate.

   ```
   StringBuilder input = new StringBuilder();
   input.append(jTextField2.getText());
   input = input.reverse();
   jTextField1.setText(input.toString());
   ```
3. I use site the flip the text, it didn't work as well.
4. I use the same site, but with `jLabel` it worked.

other method I use, but didn't work:

- Try Orientation `jTextField1.applyComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);`
- Change the IDE encoding to URT-8 (I'm using Netbeans-JDK8).

Can anyone help me how to write & print Arabic in java correctly?

Comment: when you say reverse? what exactly do you mean?

Comment: @Eugene I edit the answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the orientation of JTextArea from right to left (inside JOptionPane)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475320/how-to-set-the-orientation-of-jtextarea-from-right-to-left-inside-joptionpane)

Comment: Have you tried to set the locale? 
jTextField1.getInputContext().selectInputMethod(new Locale("ar", "LB"));

Comment: Nonetheless, a real [mcve] would be helpful. As in: putting a small class with a real main method that puts up that UI, and that people can simply run themselves to see your issue.

Comment: Please add to your question the exact sequence of Arabic characters (as text, not just as an image) that you are finding cannot be properly reversed.

Comment: @dirbacke yes, didn't work as well.

Comment: @VGR I don't know if I understand u well, but this is what i'm aiming to get: (مرحبا بالعالم)

Comment: Is that the reversed text?  If it is, then what is the original text you are inputting before reversing it?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this question -
[Forcing RTL order in a JTextArea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30579798/forcing-rtl-order-in-a-jtextarea)

Here is a sugestion to start the string with the character \u202e to force the text to be RTL.

Also i think it is not good approach to reverse the string, as it is not good user experience when the user do "copy paste", as he will copy reversed string...

Comment: I added the code `jTextField1.getDocument().putProperty(
        TextAttribute.RUN_DIRECTION,
        TextAttribute.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL);` but didn't work with.

Answer (score 1):

A string entirely composed of characters from the Arabic block should render with correct RTL presentation without any directionality control characters. If it does not, it is likely that you have a problem with your operating system configuration, not with your Java code. Reversing the string is a terrible idea. Trying for visual-order rendering is going to get all messed up.

Comment: I added the code `jTextField1.getDocument().putProperty(
        TextAttribute.RUN_DIRECTION,
        TextAttribute.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL);` but didn't work with.